# How to make MySQL between more inclusive?

Tags: mysql

Part of my SQL query includes

```
"select * from table where Name between 'a' and 'variable'";
```

I pass the variable to the query and it's a single letter a-z. If I pass it 'k', my query doesn't return names which start with 'k'. This makes sense, because 'kane' comes after 'k'. How do I get around this? I tried 'between 'a' and 'variable%' but that didn't work.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? It's a legitimate question.

Using Name >= 'a' and Name <= 'variable' doesn't work also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should concat the letter 'z' to your variable as many times as necessary to reach the length of the column `Name`.

```
select * from table where Name between 'a' and RPAD('variable',len,'z');
```

`len` should be the maximun length of the column `Name`.